# Collect terms according to elements of a vector

Tags: vector

I have a vector u, with elements u[1],u[2],...u[n].

I then have an expression with terms that are linear in u[1],u[2],...u[n].

How can I collect these terms and group them as coefficients of u[1],u[2],...,u[n] without me having to explicitly state what n is?

When the collecting is actually done, n will be known, but I want to keep n arbitrary up to that point, and so need a method that works whichever value of n I pick.

**New Issue:** Similar to the above, but now for an input n, I have n^2 variables uu[1,1],...uu[1,n],...,[n,1],...,uu[n,n]. I want to cllect terms according to these variables. I've tried doing what I did before, writing down Array[uu,{n+1,n+1}], but this isn't working.

Comment: Don't worry, I figured it out. I needed to put Array[u,n] as the terms to collect, rather than just u (where u was previously defined by Array[u,n]).

Comment: Could somoene help with the extra bit added on now?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something along these lines:

Here's an expression linear in `u[_]`. I am assuming that some `u[_]` is actually present in the expression.

```
expr = 10 u[1] + 8 u[4];
```

Extract all variables (treating the expression as a polynomial), select those that match `u[_]`, and find the largest index.

```
maxIndex = Cases[Variables[expr], _u][[All, 1]] // Max
(* 4 *)
```

Construct the variables `u[1], u[2], ..., u[maxIndex]`, and extract their coefficients.

```
Coefficient[expr, u /@ Range[maxIndex]]
(* {10, 0, 0, 8} *)
```

Comment: Could I extend this to having a matrix of variables u[i,j] (in fact, u is actually only a tridiagonal matrix) without having to manually move the elements into a list?